# bulk from exceel sheet

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-modules

we have an excel sheet has categories and sub categories we need to bulk it to database using drupe module anyone can help us?

sheet format:
SongName singerName   album  [ToneName] [Discribtion] [ToneCode] Category

```
category
   singerName
      album
        songName
```

is there drupal module can do that?

I am saving these data as taxonomy(term)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv

I used it once for the same requirement you have.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the drupal [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) Module. It will let you do a csv import one time or repeatedly.